# Should I use PUT over POST for adding "relations"?

Tags: api, rest, http

I have construct called **applications** and users can favorite them. I was thinking of having two APIs:

`PUT /api/v1/applications/:id/favorite`

`DELETE /api/v1/applications/:id/favorite`

I was wondering if it's bad practice to use PUT instead of POST. When researching a lot of people say it should be a resource/file that you are creating. This creates an entry in a table but it's meant for connecting two things together. Arguably not really a resource/entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new resource or fully replacing an existing one  at this location:

```
/api/v1/applications/:id/favorite
```

Then `PUT` is the most appropriate.